# Booksleve: what Redis version to use?

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve

With reference to [this post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-open-source-projects/) about [Booksleeve](http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/) and to the fact that there is not an official Windows [Redis distribuition](http://redis.io/download), what is the best practice? Is better to compile on Win32 or the "Unofficial" win32/64 distribuition is reliable and mantained ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booksleeve is just any-other-redis-client, and is rather orthogonal to the redis-server version/platform that you choose to use. Personally, I would only *currently* use the win32 implementations of redis-server as a local developer convenience. Production machines should probably use the linux build (we use ubuntu server, if it matters). The reason for this comes down to the simple fact that redis-server is designed to make use of the cheap linux fork/copy-on-write functionality to perform background saving (and possibly other functionality). Windows **does not have** such a fork, and the "linux on windows" implementations typically do a memory copy (pretty expensive, and may significantly impact how certain operations perform).

Worse: at least one pure-windows version of redis-server simply substitutes a `BGSAVE` request for a `SAVE` request; on an busy server, this is *death*: `SAVE` is synchronous, and redis is *single threaded*, usually simply exploiting the fact that individual operations are so ridiculously fast, so that you wouldn't normally notice. However: if you suddenly get a `SAVE` request that takes 20 seconds, then your redis server is doing ***nothing else*** for those 20 seconds.  When you are relying on replies that are typically around 0.3ms, this is a **big problem**.

Microsoft have been working on a port of redis-server, and it *may well be* that this is now production ready; however, all things considered, ***for now*** I would rather stick with the primary, well-tested implementation on a linux server.

But: for ad-hoc developer usage, any of the win32 builds should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for specifying you are using a linux Redis implementation: It does matter for whom using Windows server only.